# MSI afterburner is showing 0MHz for the core clock

Tags: water-cooling

I have run a MSI afterburner 2.1.0 for a while. I have two 6950s on my rig, watercooled, and with the msiafterburner.cfg unofficial overclock enabled.

For months I have run at 1150MV / 950MHz core / 310MHz memory / fan speed 25% on both cards. They sit nicely in the 40C range (all 3 core sensors), along with the vregs.

Recently, my water pump was overheating and not circulating - causing the cards to overheat a little to the point of shutting down my computer.

Now I can only change the overclock settings of one of the cards, the other shows this weird screen:

[image]

I couldn't find a similar screen in Google or on this exchange - so I thought I could make a topic should someone down the road experience the same.

Any suggestions will be appreciated, and I will keep this updated with any solutions.

Comment: This happen to me after installing 11.6 drivers, only on GPU not having a display connected to it. MSI should update their software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very strange...

I had to go into AMD vision engine control center -> desktop management -> creating and arranging desktops

Then I had to click on my second display, and change it to portrait. For some reason, this fixed it...

So weird.